# Web Audio : Play stereo (2 channel) mp3 so only hear channel 1 in left ear and channel 2 in right

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a stereo mp3 file. Is it possible using Web Audio to play the file so that channel 1 is only heard through the left speaker and channel 2 is only heard through the right speaker?

I've played with splitter, panner and merger nodes (channelCounts, Interpretation, CountMode) however the result always seem to be mixed somewhere e.g. if I attach a blank source as a second input to the merger, I still always hear channel 1 clearly in the right speaker.

See below as an example I have tried - with various permutations of connect ins and outs.

```
audioCtx = new window.AudioContext();
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);  

var blank = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

var splitter = audioCtx.createChannelSplitter(2);
source.connect(splitter);

var panner = audioCtx.createPanner();
panner.setPosition(-1,0,0);
splitter.connect(panner, 0, 0);

var merger = audioCtx.createChannelMerger(2);  
panner.connect(merger, 0, 0);
blank.connect(merger, 0, 1);

merger.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232597/how-to-have-a-different-sound-on-each-ear-in-js, which is very smiilar.

Comment: Great! Many thanks! 
The culprit was the realtek audio. With no way to configure the device not to mix the channels, I went and removed the device driver. However this was not easy and had to resort on "Driver store explorer" to manually ensure no drivers existed for the device. Finally the device ended up using a Microsoft one and all sounds as expected.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a pretty serious problem with the driver.  Never expected that.  But I'm glad it's working like it should now.